# Can't connect to MongoDB from an ASP.Net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mongodb

I downloaded the driver (version 2.4.4) and first I just want to connect and read some existing data.

So I tried everything I found online. Here's my code:

```
MongoClientSettings settings = new MongoClientSettings();
settings.Server = new MongoServerAddress(connectionString, 27017);
var client = new MongoClient(settings);
```

my connectionString looks like this:

```
mongodb://x.x.x.x
```

and the error I'm getting is:

```
 An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in 
 MongoDB.Driver.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

 Additional information: 'mongodb://x.x.x.x:27017' is not a valid end point.
```

I couldn't find this error anywhere online. Please help :)

**edit: I'm not using localhost and am running a real IP. the x.x.x.x is just for the question purpose.**

Answer (score 1):

You need to get rid of the "mongodb://" part of your host parameter. So instead of

```
settings.Server = new MongoServerAddress("mongodb://x.x.x.x", 27017);
```

use

```
settings.Server = new MongoServerAddress("x.x.x.x", 27017);
```

or even just

```
settings.Server = new MongoServerAddress("x.x.x.x");
```

since 27017 is the default port.

Answer (score 0):

Well x.x.x.x is not a valid address. If you're running mongodb locally you can use:

```
var url = new MongoUrl("mongodb://localhost:27017");
var client = new MongoClient(url);
```

Comment: obviously I just put this because I can't say the real IP. The ip I'm running is a valid ip of course. and I don't run in locally, I have mongo in a different server, hence the ip.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but I think I've had this issue when I forgot to whitelist the IP of my ASP server in my mongodb hosting service